# How or Where Can I Access My Vault OIDC Logs and JWT Claim Metadata

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, openid-connect, hashicorp-vault, terraform-provider-vault

I have set up a local instance of HashiCorp Vault (Enterprise edition) to test an implementation of Vault and Azure AD Single Sign-On with OIDC. I am using Terraform to provision and configure my OIDC components in Visual Studio Code, but have run into an error (see below) relating to my token claim.

[image]

How or where can I access my oidc jwt claim metadata to verify some of its entries? I have even set the `verbose_oidc_logging = true` in my `vault_jwt_auth_backend_role` configuration but can't figure out where I can access the log.

Below is the full snippet of vault_jwt_auth_backend_role configuration.

```
resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend_role" "azure" {
  role_name             = var.azure_role_name 
  backend               = vault_jwt_auth_backend.root.path
  user_claim            = "email"
  groups_claim          = "groups" 
  
  bound_claims          = { "groups": "VaultAdmins" }
  
  role_type             = "oidc"
  oidc_scopes           = var.oidc_scopes 
  allowed_redirect_uris = var.allowed_redirect_uris
  verbose_oidc_logging  = "true"
```

}

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but I think I remeber AzureAD sends the group's ID in the claim, not the group name. +Does authentication work if you remove `groups_clain` and `bound_claims` ?

Answer (score 1):

How you access the tokens will depend on which flow the app is using.

If it's an implicit flow, you should be able to see the tokens in the payload of the HTTP request during sign-on.

If it's an authorization code flow (likely), you can use Postman to form a request, and you'll need a few values from the Azure AD app registration for your app.

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `tenant_Id` | Azure AD tenant ID |
| `client_Id` | Azure AD application (client) ID |
| `client_secret` | Client secret created for your app |
| `redirect_url` | The redirect URL where the token is being sent |
| `scopes` | The API permissions the app is requesting |

## Obtain authorization code

Use the above info to form a link to login to your application, the link should be URL encoded.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_Id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&response_type=code&response_mode=query&scope={scopes}&state=12345
```

Example

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/abcde123-a123-1a23-b9a9-123a456bcd7d/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapplication.azurewebsites.net%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback&client_id=a1bcde23-a12b-1234-1a2b-1a23456b78cd&scope=openid%20profile%20email&response_mode=query&state=12345
```

Open a browser window with the developer tools open, and login to your app using the link. After Azure AD successfully authenticates you, you should see a request with a `code` in the payload. This is the authorization code that will be used to exchange for your tokens. Copy this value.

[image]

## Make a Postman call

**Method**
POST

**URL**
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token`

**Headers**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Content-Type | application/x-www-form-urlencoded |

**Body**

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| client_id | `client_id` |
| client_secret | `client_secret` |
| code | `code` |
| grant_type | authorization_code |
| redirect_url | `redirect_url` |
| scope | `scopes` |

## Result

You can see the access token and the ID token in the request body

[image]

Comment: scottwtang, that is absolutely awesome!! I will most definitely try out all your suggestions, notably in Postman. Will provide some feedback shortly.