# Error "AADSTS50076" while getting the User Access Token

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get the user access token for accessing Graph APIs from the node.js code.

```
My Request: 
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<AD-Tenant-Id>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <application ID>
client_secret: <secret string>
scope: User.Read
response_type: "code"
grant_type: "password"
username: <user email>
password: <user password>
```

```
I get error: 
AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator,
or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access....
```

I am using postman for testing the request.
In my AD I have multi-factor authentication disabled.
And "Security Defaults" are set to "enable".
If I "disable" the "Security Defaults", then I am able to get the token.

Is there a way I can keep the "Security Defaults" enabled and get the token, without the user interaction?

Comment: You can use the Authorization Code flow, which is a 2-step process where the user authenticates first and receives a code value, and then the code can be run through Postman to get the token. See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72825112/18748575)

Comment: I need to avoid user interaction while generating the user token.

Comment: Silent flows such as the password flow, do not support MFA at all. The only way to acquire a token for a user with MFA enabled is to use an interactive flow, such as the authorization code flow. The password flow is not recommended to be used at all anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out Get access on behalf of a user , ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token

POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111

&scope=user.read%20mail.read

&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...

&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F

&grant_type=authorization_code

&client_secret=jXoM3iz...

Hope this will help.

Comment: As per my understanding the `code` passed in the request is generated by user login to MS. I don't want to have user interaction, get user token must be done entirely from the  backend when AD "Security Defaults" are enabled. When "Security Defaults" are not enabled then it does work.

Comment: could you please try client credential flow - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow , make sure you You must use application permissions, you can't use delegated permissions because there is no user for your app to act on behalf of. , also known as app roles, that are granted by an admin or by the API's owner. let us know if that works .

Comment: I need to get the user token, I know we can get the application token. but the Graph APIs that I am trying to use require user delegated permissions. So I need to use user token.